# Testing Use of Class Optionally Included in Project

Tags: php, phpspec

I have a class that goes something like the following:

```
class Foo {

  /**
   * @var array|Bar
   */
  protected $source;

  public function __construct($source = []) {
    if (class_exists(Bar::class)) {
      $source = new Bar($source);
    }

    $this->source = $source;
  }

  public function getSource() {
    return $this->source;
  }

  // ...

}
```

`Bar` comes from a separate PHP package, an optional dependency listed in `suggest` section of `composer.json`.

I want to write two separate expectations in phpspec for `getSource()`

```
function it_provides_array_source_by_default() {
  $this->getSource()->shouldBeArray();
}

function it_provides_bar_instance_when_available() {
  $this->getSource()->shouldReturnAnInstanceOf(Bar::class);
}
```

I can't test the `shouldBeArray()` if my `require-dev` for the package includes the dependency containing `Bar`.

I can't mock `Bar` like:

```
function it_provides_bar_instance_when_available(Bar $bar) {
  $this->getSource()->shouldReturnAnInstanceOf(Bar::class);
}
```

because I get a phpspec error:

> [PhpSpec\Exception\Locator\ResourceCreationException]
>     Can not find appropriate suite scope for class `Bar`.

**What is the best-practice method for testing the return value being an optional class like this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the logic that selects the type of `$source` into an external factory function.

```
class Foo {

  protected $source;

  public function __construct($source = []) {
    $this->source = $source;
  }

}

class FooFactory {

  public get() {
    $source = [];
    if (class_exists(Bar::class)) {
      $source = new Bar($source);
    }

    return new Foo($source);
  }

}
```

This allows you to explicitly test `Foo` both ways *and* decouples the implementation by moving everything to a dependency injected model.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd prefer to avoid a factory for my specific implementation. I suppose I could have some `AbstractFoo` as you have `Foo` in your answer *(working with the array source directly)*, and have `Foo extends AbstractFoo` with my implementation checking for `Bar`. I could stub `AbstractFoo` for the array tests, and use `Foo` directly for the `Bar` tests. Even with this though, it feels wrong to abstract the class *just* for testing.

Comment: It really rubs me the wrong way that you have `Bar` hardcoded in your constructor to begin with. For that alone you should move it out and into a factory.

Comment: Thanks again for this. Though testing factories with phpspec comes with it's own set of difficulties, I think I'm all set now.